# How do I print the actual contents of this list

Tags: oop, list, python-3.x

The code is short and simple:

```
class Contact:
    all_contacts = []

    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        Contact.all_contacts.append(self)


c1 = Contact("Paul", "something@hotmail.com")
c2 = Contact("Darren", "another_thing@hotmail.com")
c3 = Contact("Jennie", "different@hotmail.com")


for i in Contact.all_contacts:
    print(i)
```

Clearly all I want to do is print the 'all_contacts' list with the info I have added, but what I get is:

```
<__main__.Contact object at 0x2ccf70>
<__main__.Contact object at 0x2ccf90>
<__main__.Contact object at 0x2ccfd0>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your Contact class:

```
class Contact:
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s <%s>' % (self.name, self.email)
```

This will tell Python how to render your object in a human-readable string representation.

[Reference information for **str**](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

Answer (score 1):

The `__repr__` and `__str__` methods for `Contact` aren't defined, so you get this default string representation instead.

```
def __str__(self):
    return '<Contact %s, %s>' % (self.name, self.email)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Separate the container from the items stored in the container.
2. Add a `__str__()` method to `Contact`.

   ```
   class Contact:
       def __init__(self, name, email):
           self.name = name
           self.email = email
       def __str__(self):
           return "{} <{}>".format(self.name, self.email)

   class ContactList(list):
       def add_contact(self, *args):
           self.append(Contact(*args))

   c = ContactList()
   c.add_contact("Paul", "something@hotmail.com")
   c.add_contact("Darren", "another_thing@hotmail.com")
   c.add_contact("Jennie", "different@hotmail.com")

   for i in c:
       print(i)
   ```